# Subarray With Max Average And Lower-Bounded Length

Tags: algorithm

Given an array with `n` elements. Call `T(i, L) = (a[i] + a[i + 1] + ... + a[i + L - 1])/L (1 <= i < n - L)` with the condition that `L >= K`. Find the maximum of `T(i, L)`

Input:

- First line is two integers with `N, K (1 <= n <= 3e5)`
- Second line with `N` non-negative elements `(0 <= a[i] <= 1e6)`
  Output:
- Print out the maximum of `T(i, L)` with `L >= K`

Sample Input:
4 1
1 0 4 3
Sample Output:
4
Sample Input:
5 2
2 4 3 4 1
Sample Output:
3.666667

I just have a solution with the complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: There's always an optimal subarray with size less than 2K

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has an O(n) solution, but I have to think about it.  Certainly can do O(n log K). Will probably write later if the question isn't closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing ideas from Matt Timmermans and David Eisenstat, here is a `O(n)` solution.

As Matt Timmermans pointed out, there is an optimal solution of length at most `2k`.  Therefore we only need to look for solutions of lengths from `k` to `2k`.

As David Eisenstat pointed out in a now deleted comment, we can look for solutions that pass through a given point by first preparing a list of the efficient suffixes in the left side and a list of the efficient prefixes in the right side. By "efficient" we mean that every other eligible prefix or suffix either is shorter or has a lesser average.  And we're only interested in prefixes and suffixes of length at most `2k-1` There is a one-pass `O(k)`-time algorithm for this that uses a stack.

Now reverse the suffix list so that we can start by pairing good long prefixes with very good short suffixes.  In pseudo-code:

```
while we have at least one suffix and prefix:
    if the sum of the lengths < k:
        move to the next suffix to look at longer candidates
    else
        if it is better than our current best candidate:
            save our optimal candidate
        move to the next prefix to look for better candidates
```

There are at most `O(k)` good suffixes and prefixes.  This will go through the list in `O(k)` time.  Therefore in `O(k)` time we'll find all possible optimal solutions passing through a point.

Now start from the end of the array.  Pick a point `k-1` forward. Look for all solutions passing through that point.  Cut off the end of the array.  Repeat while there is enough array left to find more solutions.

The result is that we eliminate possible solutions in `O(k)` of the array in `O(k)` time.  After recursing we process the entire `O(n)` array in `O(n)` time.

Comment: This is very nice